# Pstricks: Hunderds of thousands on the vertical axis

Tags: pstricks

Feeding

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{pst-all}
\begin{document}
%\renewcommand{\psvlabel}[1]{#1000}%%% the label is appended with 000, i.e., is printed as thousands. Unfortunately, this append 000 also to zero. Perhaps, we could write “if #1=0 then 0 else #1000” as the body of the macro \psvlabel, but I've failed to code this conditional statement in (La)TeX properly so far.
\begin{pspicture}(-2,-1)(1,4.5)
  \psaxes[Dy=25,dy=.4cm,xAxis=false]{->}(0,0)(107,4.5)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

to `latex` followed by `dvips` yields

[image: output]

How to get the numbers 0, 25000, 50000, … 250000 instead of 0, 25, 50, … 250 as labels of the ticks on the vertical axis? About 12 years ago, saying `Dy=25000` instead of `Dy=25` did the job, but now we get “! Dimension too large“ if we do so.

Btw., we DO want to compile via latex+dvips, DO want to have a zero label, do NOT want an exponential notation (0, 25⋅10³, 50⋅10³, …, 250⋅10³), and do NOT want a TikZ solution.

Comment: `\makeatletter \def\pst@@@vlabel#1{#1\ifnum#1=0\else000\fi} \makeatother` would probably work.

Comment: @JasperHabicht It does!!! Thx!!!

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{pst-all}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-2,-1)(1,4.5)
\psaxes[ylabelFontSize=\scriptstyle,ylabelFactor=000,showorigin=false,
        Dy=25,dy=0.4cm,xAxis=false]{->}(0,0)(107,4.5)
\psyTick(0){\scriptstyle0}             
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

and this: `ylabelFactor=\,000` looks nicer:

[image]

Comment: Thx! In financial English texts, I think, you could probably wish to say `ylabelFactor={,000}` instead of `ylabelFactor=\,000`.  In financial German text, you could probably use `ylabelFactor=.000`. Anyway, I'm typesetting maths rather than finances, so `000` is perfect. `\psyTick(0){\scriptstyle0}` is news to me; thx again!